# Regex get only the datas which has spaces

Tags: python-3.x

need to get the search only for the word which has spaces for e.g.: if its "makeready" it's should not take it only "make ready" with space

```
import re
a = "This is to be in makeready of the part"
b = re.search("^.*(make ready|make\s*[\_\-\s]*\s*ready|make-ready|:make ready).*$",a)
if b:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Required output: `no`

Comment: What is the problem with your current script?

Comment: if it is "makeready"  without space it is getting yes

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem with your regex is the following alternation term:

```
make\s*[\_\-\s]*\s*ready
```

This actually matches `makeready`, since the content in between `make` and `ready` is optional.  I would suggest the following pattern:

```
\bmake[\s_-]+ready\b
```

Updated script:

```py
a = "This is to be in make-ready of the part"
b = re.search(r'\bmake[\s_-]+ready\b', a)
if b:
    print("yes")  # prints 'yes'
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: @Ajay If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be appreciated.